# Show a multivariable function is differentiable at a point

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Define $F(x,y)=(x^2, xy + y^2)$.  How do I show that $F(x,y)$ is differentiable at the point $A=(a,b)$ without using any known theorems?

Am I correct by showing that the limit exists, i.e. $lim_{h \to 0} (FA+h)-F(h)/h$?

I broke it up into two parts, first, holding 'b' constant and then having $a + h \to h$ as $h \to 0$.  Then I held 'a' constant and did $b + h \to b$ as $h \to 0$.  This got me all 4 partial derivatives, which I know are correct.

Is this the correct approach, or am I missing any other important steps?

Comment: Um wasn't this just asked once?

Comment: The linear map $L$ is the map determined by the jacobian matrix (in the standard basis).

Comment: That's the only definition for differentiability you have been taught?

Comment: No, but I need to prove it by not using any theorems.  I know that the limit should also exist, but am confused on how to take the limit of a multivariable function.